FXSampler App for ControlsFX finds no samples using Zulu JDK-FX 17
I'm trying to get the FXSampler App for ControlsFX running.
It starts, seemingly OK, but finds no Samples.
I'm using the Zulu JDK-FX 17, which has JavaFX built-in.
IDE is Eclipse 2024-03, under Windows 10.
I have included the following via pom.xml:
Maven Dependencies
The App starts, with no contents. Here's a Screenshot:
FXSampler App Screenshot
The Console Log shows this:

Initialising FXSampler sample scanner...
    Discovering projects...
        Found project 'ControlsFX', with sample base package 'org.controlsfx.samples'


Can anyone help?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

The world does not need brainless bots, posting senseless responses. There IS no code to post. That is clear from the posted Screenshots.
